# Lead standard object layout when install app does not changed

Tags: salesforce

Can anyone help me for this issue?

We created a Salesforce app, and in it, we added a custom field with a related list in the Lead standard object. When we install the app, the layout of Lead does not automatically update like we expect it would. Is there any way to ensure it *does* update?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I made some significant grammatical and formatting edits to make it more readable, but for future reference, please check out the [editing help](//$SITEURL$/editing-help), so you can format your questions better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use the metadata api to make an update to the page layout to achieve this but that would have to be done post install of your package. It also requires adding the instance URL to the the remote site settings. See [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) for appreciate code that wraps the metadata api.  It might be more simple to just include a visual force page with post setup instructions that walk the user through the steps